# Out of box Salesforce?

Tags: oob

What does salesforce out of the box mean? I came across this term and couldn't find any documentation. If anyone could explain or suggest any references, it will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It's just an english expression ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_feature . you'll however see people using it with slightly different meanings all over the place.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Thanks for the wiki link. The wifi example made it easy to understand that term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Salesforce out of the box means the declarative features provided by the Salesforce, where we can develop applications just by using button clicks and without any code e.g. **workflow/approval process**,reports and **dashboards** . It mainly has features for linking salesforce with Outlook.

Answer (score 6):

**No Code, No Programming.** [Here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gubGAAQ) is a reference.

Answer (score 2):

"out of the box" (sometimes OOB) means to say just by using only standard objects and configuration without any custom/coding

Answer (score 1):

out of box functionalty means salesforce provide some predefined functinalities (declarative development) firstly we obey the functinalities .if customer wants his own business requirement.then we need to go for customization.